# What is the best way to get the max id of table?

Tags: jdbc

What is the best way to get the max id of table? Below I have paste the error and code. So I was planning on using afterLast() method to get the max id but I get an error.

**ERROR:**

```
SQLException: feature not supported
```

**Code:**

```
public class ex03 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/dave_000/My_WorkSpace/Eclipse_Workspaces/workspace-jsp/T_01_JDBC_01.accdb";

    Connection con;

    // Get Max ID
    Statement stmt0;
    String query0 = "select * from user";

    try {
        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
    } catch (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.print("ClassNotFoundException: ");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "", "");
        stmt0 = con.createStatement();


        // Get last ID
        ResultSet rs = stmt0.executeQuery(query0);
        rs.afterLast();
        int maxID = rs.getInt("ID");
        System.out.println(maxID);


        pstmt1.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.err.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please add `ex.printStackTrace();` to your `catch` block and add the result to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is much more efficient to use SQL to find the maximum value:

```
select max(id) from user
```